# Export sql server Query Result in Excel file

Tags: php, sql

I have code to export mysql query result data into Excel. But Now I use SQL Server.I haven't idea to fetch number of fields name. I find many blogs but they all are display php function of mysql database. I need php function which usefull to get field name and number from SQL Query Result

```
        $header = '';
        $result = '';

        $exportData = sqlsrv_query($gaSql['link'], $sQuery) or die("$sQuery: " . sqlsrv_errors());
        $fields = mysql_num_fields($exportData);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++) {
            if (in_array(mysql_field_name($exportData, $i), $_POST['optFieldName'])) {
                $header .= mysql_field_name($exportData, $i) . "\t";
            }
    //        $header .= mysql_field_name($exportData, $i) . "\t";
        }
    //    

        $row = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($exportData); $i++) {
            $result_excel = mysql_fetch_array($exportData);
            array_push($row, $result_excel);
        }
        foreach ($row as $rowvalue) {
            $line = '';
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($_POST['optFieldName']); $j++) {
                $value = $rowvalue[$_POST['optFieldName'][$j]];
                if ((!isset($value) ) || ( $value == "" )) {
                    $value = "\t";
                } else {
                    $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
                    $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
                }
                $line .= $value;
            }
            $result .= trim($line) . "\n";
        }

        $result = str_replace("\r", "", $result);

        if ($result == "") {
            $result = "\nNo Record(s) Found!\n";
        }

        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        print "$header\n$result";
```

Comment: What output you are getting ?

Comment: i use sql server so all mysql function is going wrong here.